# Collapsing factor level for all the factor variable in dataframe based on the count

Tags: r, lapply

I would like to keep only the top 2 factor levels based on the frequency and group all other factors into Other. I tried this but it doesn't help.

```
df=data.frame(a=as.factor(c(rep('D',3),rep('B',5),rep('C',2))), 
              b=as.factor(c(rep('A',5),rep('B',5))), 
              c=as.factor(c(rep('A',3),rep('B',5),rep('C',2)))) 

myfun=function(x){
    if(is.factor(x)){
        levels(x)[!levels(x) %in% names(sort(table(x),decreasing = T)[1:2])]='Others'  
    }
}

df=as.data.frame(lapply(df, myfun))
```

Expected Output

```
       a b      c
       D A      A
       D A      A
       D A      A
       B A      B
       B A      B
       B B      B
       B B      B
       B B      B
  others B others
  others B others
```

Comment: you want to calculate the frequency of the factors for the entire data frame or column ? Please share your expected output.

Comment: It would only be for a single variable, i keep only the top 2 factor based on the frequency and group all the other levels as other.

Comment: Can you add the expected output, given the above data frame?

Comment: @sotos this would work, thanks for the hint.fun1 <- function(x){
    x=factor(x, levels = names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)));
    levels(x) <- c(names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[1:2]), rep('others', length(levels(x))-2)); 
return(x)
}

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli I deleted it as it was messing with the order but yes you got the point :)

Comment: @ yeah i got that but then we would have to first reorder the levels in the decreasing order and then do what you did. you could put it as an anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might get a bit messy, but here is one approach via base R,

```
fun1 <- function(x){levels(x) <- 
                    c(names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[1:2]), 
                    rep('others', length(levels(x))-2)); 
                    return(x)}
```

However the above function will need to first be re-ordered and as OP states in comment, the correct one will be,

```
fun1 <- function(x){ x=factor(x, 
                     levels = names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE))); 
                     levels(x) <- c(names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[1:2]), 
                     rep('others', length(levels(x))-2)); 
                     return(x) }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is now easy thanks to `fct_lump()` from the `forcats` package.

```
fct_lump(df$a, n = 2)

# [1] D     D     D     B     B     B     B     B     Other Other
# Levels: B D Other
```

The argument `n` controls the number of most common levels to be preserved, lumping together the others.